# Is there an easy way to convert from NifTi (.nii) image format to .inr?

Tags: c++, cgal, nifti

I would like to use the [surface_mesher](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesher/index.html#Chapter_3D_Surface_Mesh_Generation) of the CGAL library.

I managed to successfully compile the example mesh_a_3d_gray_image.cpp.

But when I try to use it with my own data which are in NifTi format (.nii), I run into the problem that it is not supported by CGAL. It seems that the only supported format is .inr, which doesn't seem to be very commonly used.

I tried to convert my data to other formats which seemed to be supported by CGAL, as specified in ImageIO_impl.h, but none of them could be succesfully imported.

I didn't find any tool to convert from NifTi to .inr. I found this old post:
[Troubles understanding .inr file format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34906509/troubles-understanding-inr-file-format)

It describes the .inr format, but doesn't hint to tools which could do the conversion I am looking for.

So is there a simple tool which can convert from NifTi to .inr?

Comment: Looking through CGAL's documentation, it looks like they're image loader also supports ANALYZE images.  You should be able to find more documentation/converters for that format.  IIRC it's mainly a text header file and then a raw image file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really answering the question as I will tell you how to directly use NifTi images in CGAL.

From [here](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/master/Polyhedron/demo/Polyhedron/Plugins/Mesh_3/Io_image_plugin.cpp) you can see that such files could be used with code like the following:

```
    vtkNew<vtkNIFTIImageReader> reader;
    reader->SetFileName(fileinfo.filePath().toUtf8());
    reader->Update();
    auto vtk_image = reader->GetOutput();
    vtk_image->Print(std::cerr);
    *image = CGAL::IO::read_vtk_image_data(vtk_image); // copy the image data
```

Comment: You might take the cpp in this pull request: https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/pull/7823